# A minor CSS issue about footer

Tags: html, css

This is my simple webpage :-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .body{
                max-width:3072px;
                min-width:3072px;
                margin:0px auto;
                background: url('Stripes.png') no-repeat #293231;
                background-attachment:fixed;
                background-position:0% 25%;
            }
            .back{
                z:index:0;

            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="body">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src='Main.jpg' class="back"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src='Page2.jpg'/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src='Page3.jpg'/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src='MiddleLeft.png'/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src='MiddleMiddle.png'/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src='MiddleRight.png'/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src='footer.jpg'/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src='footer.jpg'/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src='footer.jpg'/>
                </td>

            </tr>


        </table>


    </body>
</html>
```

Problem here is due to my large monitor the footer doesn't appear at the bottom of the monitor. It appears somewhere in the middle. How do i ensure that footer appears only at the bottom of the screen irrespective of the size of the screen?

Comment: Consider not using tables for layout like this. Use floating <divs> instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at:

[A Bulletproof Sticky Footer, Woohoo!](http://css-tricks.com/sticky-footer/)